# I want to see open cases in my visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="displaycase">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!getcasetype}" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!casestatus}"> </apex:selectOptions>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displaycaselist}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:outputLabel id="pnl1" >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caselst}" var="cse">
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.CaseNumber}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.Subject}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.Type}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.Priority}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.Reason}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.Status}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.IsEscalated}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.IsClosed}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cse.ClosedDate}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### Apex class

```
public class displaycase {
    public string getcasetype{get;set;}
    public  void displaycase (){

    }
    public list<case> caselst{get;set;}
    public list<selectoption>getcasestatus(){
        list<selectoption>selectopt=new list<selectoption>();
        selectopt.add(new selectoption('New','New'));
        selectopt.add(new selectoption('Working','Working'));
        selectopt.add(new selectoption('Escalated','Escalated'));
        selectopt.add(new selectoption('Closed','Closed'));
        return selectopt;
    }
    public void displaycaselist(){
        caselst=new list<case>();
        caselst=[SELECT CaseNumber,ClosedDate,IsClosed,IsEscalated,Priority,Reason,Status,Subject,Type FROM Case where status=:getcasetype];
    }
}
```

Here I want to further refine my result on the basis of more standard picklist field Type, Reason, Origin and Priority at case object, what changes required in apex class visualforce page.

Give me an example with 1 more piclist Type(I have Under Warranty, Under AMC and Out of Warranty values for type picklist at case object) rest I do it for balance.

Here I also want to know how we can set default value for status piclist or any other picklist otherwise  no records will show on page when I see the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

You can try below,

```
public void displaycaselist()
{
    caselst=new list<case>();
    String query = 'select CaseNumber,ClosedDate,IsClosed,IsEscalated,Priority,Reason,Status,Subject,Type FROM Case where id!=null';
    if(getcasetype!=null ){
       query+=' and status=\''+getcasetype+'\'';
    }
    //you can include other filters as below
    /*
    if(getPriority!=null ){
       query+=' and priority=\''+getPriority+'\'';
    }
    */
    caselst=Database.query(query);
}
```

Comment: Please suggest corresponding changes in visaulforce page also, I'm confused my priority picklist is having standard values Major, Minor and Critical.

Comment: your current visualforce code will work with this class code. No need to update. Try n let me know

Comment: Here I want to shown 1 more picklist at my visualforce page for user input like status picklist shown.

Comment: it will be similar to what u have done for status.

Comment: <apex:selectOptions value="{!casestatus}"> </apex:selectOptions> I'm confused in this line of code what is {!casestatus} for priority picklist what should we our line of code .

Comment: what other picklist field you want?

Comment: {!casestatus} provides option values for picklist. it comes from method getcasestatus(). for {!priority} write a method getPriority() similar to getcasestatus().

Comment: One picklist for Status  and second picklist for priority selection at visualforce page and then want to populate the required result through dispalycaselist method.

Comment: Pl don't mind if I ask, how {!casestatus} comes from method getcasestatus()

Comment: Pl don't mind I'm new for this technology, APEX and Visualforce etc and here I'm trying to understand this code.

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm